# How to use css with Code Runner

Tags: html, css, coderunner

Hi if anyone knows how to use Code Runner, how would I link an html file to a css file. Does Code Runner even support css?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well it doesn't matter which IDE or Editor you are using.

In order to add a css spreadsheet to your HTML page, you must use the `<link>` tag.

[HTML link tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```